# Como puedo insertar varias filas en una BD desde Laravel

Tags: laravel

Este es mi codigo y lo que necesito es guardar un detalle de factura, tengo un encabezado (cliente, serie, numero) que se guarda una sola vez (no hay problema con esto), el problema es cuando intento guardar el detalle (producto, cantidad) este detalle puede tener mas de un producto y obviamente el mismo numero de cantidades, el $request me tira todos los valores como un array ya que así se los puse en los inputs name='nombre[]' pero me da error.

codigo de mi controlador:

```
$factura_enc = new fac_enc;
      $factura_det = new fac_det;
      $factura_enc->numero = $request->input('nofac');
      $factura_enc->id_cliente = $request->input('idcliente');
      $factura_enc->save();
      foreach ($factura_det as $detalle) {
        $detalle->id_fac_enc = $request->input('nofac');
        $detalle->id_producto = $request->input('idproducto[]');
        $detalle->cantidad = $request->input('cantproducto[]');
        $detalle->save();
      }
```

y este es el codigo html:

```
<input type="text" name="nofac" readonly="readonly" class="form-control">
<input type="hidden" name="idproducto[]" v-model="prod.idpro">
<input type="hidden" name="cantproducto[]" v-model="prod.cantidad">
```

Este es el error que me da Attempt to assign property of non-object

introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se como hacer exactamente para poder enviar el insert de esos datos. si sirve de algo adjunto los datos que envia el formulario:

"idproducto":["1","2","3","4"],"cantproducto":["3","2","7","10"]

como dato extra te comento que el encabezado si me guarda, pero esta parte del detalle no.

Comment: que error te da?

Comment: Ya lo modifique me puedes ayudar?

Answer (score 0):

Tenés mal armada la lógica del loop.

Primero creas `fac_enc` y eso está bien. Pero luego tenés que crear tantos `fac_det` como `idproducto`s hayas enviado.
Estás haciendo un foreach `$factura_det`, pero eso no es un array, no tiene sentido loopear eso, deberías loopear `idproducto`.

Por último, veo que a `$detalle->id_fac_enc` le estás asignado `nofac`, pero entiendo que lo que querés hacer es asignarle el ID que se le generó a `$factura_enc`, así que te modifiqué eso. Si estoy equivocado, dejalo como estaba.

```
$factura_enc = new fac_enc;
$factura_enc->numero = $request->input('nofac');
$factura_enc->id_cliente = $request->input('idcliente');
$factura_enc->save();

foreach ($request->input('idproducto') as $i => $idProducto) {
    $detalle = new fac_det;
    $detalle->id_fac_enc = $factura_enc->id;
    $detalle->id_producto = $idProducto;
    $detalle->cantidad = $request->input('cantproducto.' . $i);
    $detalle->save();
}
```

---

**Extra:**

No se como tenés definidos los modelos y sus relaciones. Pero podrías simplificar un poco el guardado de `fac_det`. Por ejemplo, en vez de asociarle un `id_fac_enc` y usar `save()`, podrías hacer (si estoy en lo cierto en su relación):

```
$detalle = new fac_det;
$detalle->id_producto = $idProducto;
$detalle->cantidad = $request->input('cantproducto.' . $i);
$factura_enc->detalles()->save($detalle);
```

De esa manera te ahorras definir `id_fac_enc` ([save method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method)).